# efficient way to check if at least one row contains a null value in a DataView?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need  to do a test in a DataView to check if at least one row contains one cell with a null value. What is the best way to do it in your opinion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best way would be to perform the check in the DB...and let it do what it's good at.

Comment: @Mitch: We don't know what the DataView comes from.

Comment: basically I have some checkboxes bound to this DataView and I have a "isDefault" column (boolean) to say if each checkbox has to be checked or not regarding its isDefault value. My problem is that I would like to automatically set the checkbox value to false if the value from the DataView is Null because otherwise I get an error of course if it tries to bind Null to the checkbox.

Comment: so my idea was to test the DataView and not trying to bind the checkboxes if the test returned true. but maybe there is a better solution directly during the binding process

Comment: @SLaks: true. But I find most come from a database.

Answer (score 2):

As SLaks mentioned, you're going to need to loop over the rows and the items in each row. You can do this with LINQ like this:

```
bool hasNull = view.Table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Any(r => r.ItemArray.Any(o => o == DBNull.Value));
```

Or you can write the loop yourself, something like:

```
private bool HasEmptyItem(DataView view)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in view.Table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in view.Table.Columns)
        {
            if (row[col] == DBNull.Value)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

While the LINQ version is a lot more compact, it's still going to loop over the rows and columns, so take your pick.

**Update:**
Based on comments, here's a better sample based on what you're trying to do. This simply loops over the rows, and checks if a give column is null (make sure to use `DBNull.Value` with a `DataTable`), and if so, just sets it to false to prevent problems in your case. Just change `IS_DEFAULT_COL` to be the correct index.

```
const int IS_DEFAULT_COL = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in view.Table.Rows)
{
    if (row[IS_DEFAULT_COL] == DBNull.Value)
        row[IS_DEFAULT_COL] = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot wsanville !
I was thinking of this regular loop but your LinQ solution seems to be a lot more interesting and compact :)
Could you tell me your opinion about the inital problem I have and I have explained in my last comment above please ? because maybe I could solve that directly in the binding process instead of trying to test the dataview.

Comment: thanks,
I remember I tried something in my binding stuff to say "if it's null then bind with false", there is an option for that when you do checkbox.databindings.add(........) I think, but that didn't seem to work, I still got an error.

Comment: Don't call `ItemArray`; it needlessly allocates an array.

Comment: hello,
I have a problem with the linq version because I have a filter on my dataview and I only want to loop through the filtered rows, so I know how to change the regular code to do that, like this :
foreach (DataRowView drv in View)... instead of (DataRow row in view.Table.Rows)
But I don't find how to change the linq version to loop only through the filtered rows.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Without measuring, I would guess that the answer is a nested loop.

Comment: something like :

foreach (DataRow dr in TheDataView)
{ if dr["Column"] == Null ... } ?

Comment: And then loop through each column.